# How to create new google spreadsheet and add worksheets to it in a specific location in google drive using Python 3

Tags: python

I am working on a project in python that requires creating and updating google spreadsheets and worksheets in a specific location. I looked at the `gspread` package but I could not find any method to create new google spreadsheets and worksheets in a specific location. It only creates new spreadsheets in my drive. Any help on how this can be done using python would be greatly appreciated.

Edit - I also looked at the google API [link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) to create a new google spreadsheet in python but I am finding it hard to understand how to go about it as I am not a developer/programmer by profession.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation, how about https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#creating-a-spreadsheet and https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#creating-a-worksheet or https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create ?

Comment: I just updated my question to make it clearer. I want to create a new google spreadsheet is a specific location in google drive rather than in my google drive.

Comment: When you want to create new Spreadsheet in the specific folder, unfortunately, it cannot directly achieve using only Sheets API. As the workaround, 1. Create new Spreadsheet using Sheets API. At that time, Spreadsheet is created to root folder. 2. Move the folder to the specific folder using Drive API. Or, 1. Create new Spreadsheet to the specific folder using Drive API. 2. Update the Spreadsheet using Sheets API. At that time, you can add worksheets.

Comment: I am completely new to google APIs or any APIs for that matter. But I will try to look into your suggestions and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I think that in your case, the quickstart of Drive API and Sheets API are useful. You can see them at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python and https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python . For moving file using Drive API, please check https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update  If you have any questions, feel free to tell me.